# Bootstrap carousel indicators out of the main div not switching automatically

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have the latest Bootstrap, and have a carousel somewhere on my page, with the indicators outside of the main carousel div.

My carousel:

```
<div class="background-carousel">
    <div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" id="carousel-home" data-ride="carousel1">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="carousel-inner-home">
            <div data-slide-no="0" class="item carousel-item active" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/home-bg-1.png)">
            </div>
            <div data-slide-no="1" class="item carousel-item" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/grass.jpg)">
            </div>
            <div data-slide-no="2" class="item carousel-item" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/grass2.jpg)">
            </div>
            <div data-slide-no="3" class="item carousel-item" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/grass3.jpg)">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- carousel -->
</div> <!-- /.background-carousel -->
```

I then have my indicators else where on the page:

```
<div class="home-carousel-indicators">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="0" class="carousel-switcher active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="1" class="carousel-switcher"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="2" class="carousel-switcher"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="3" class="carousel-switcher"></li>
    </ol>
</div> <!-- /.home-caraousel-indicators -->
```

As the carousel switches pictures, the indicators don't change. I also had to use a workaround to get them to change the carousel when clicked.

**Summing it up:**

- My carousel works fine.
- My carousel indicators are outside of the carousel div.
- The indicators do not automatically switch when the carousel does.
- I had to use a jQuery workaround to fix the indicators when clicking them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mmayzkLs/1/)**

Well you can make use of `slide.bs.carousel` option of `bootstrap carousel` and make  the respective indicators `active` depending on the current slide as below:

```
var $carousel = $('#myCarousel'); //get a reference
$carousel.carousel(); 
$carousel.bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) { //attach its event
    var current=$(e.target).find('.item.active'); //get the current active slide
    $('.carousel-indicators li').removeClass('active') //remove active class from all the li of carousel indicator

    var indx=$(current).index(); //get its index
    if((indx+2)>$('.carousel-indicators li').length)
        indx=-1 //if index exceeds total length of indicators present set it to -1
    $('.carousel-indicators li:nth-child('+(indx+2)+')').addClass('active');//set the respective indicator active

});
```

---

**UPDATE**

The answer given above just shows how to make `indicators active` when they are placed outside the `carousel`. It is not working while `click` since I haven't handled click event for carousel indicators.. Below update fixes the same.

**[UPDATED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mmayzkLs/21/)**

```
var $carousel = $('#myCarousel');
$carousel.carousel();
var handled=false;//global variable

$carousel.bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var current=$(e.target).find('.item.active');
    var indx=$(current).index();
    if((indx+2)>$('.carousel-indicators li').length)
        indx=-1
     if(!handled)
     {
        $('.carousel-indicators li').removeClass('active')
        $('.carousel-indicators li:nth-child('+(indx+2)+')').addClass('active');
     }
     else
     {
        handled=!handled;//if handled=true make it back to false to work normally.
     }
});

$(".carousel-indicators li").on('click',function(){
   //Click event for indicators
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
   //remove siblings active class and add it to current clicked item
   handled=true; //set global variable to true to identify whether indicator changing was handled or not.
});
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: hi in your fiddle, if I click 3rd indicator, the second indicators get activated (added active class). Can you please check it?

Comment: @ilmk.. Updated answer.. Check and let me know.. Thank you for pointing.. :)

Comment: @ilmk Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 4):

For **Bootstrap 5**

`#myCarousel` is the ID of carousel whereas `#indicators` is the ID of parent div of indicators.

```
let myCarousel = document.querySelector('#myCarousel');
myCarousel.addEventListener('slide.bs.carousel', (event) => {
    let elementChildrens = document.querySelector("#indicators").children;
    elementChildrens.item(event.from).classList.remove("active");
    elementChildrens.item(event.to).classList.add("active");
});
```

HTML for Indicators:

```
<div id="indicators" class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
```

HTML for Carousel:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! clean and working code.

Answer (score 3):

Here an even more simplified example of Guruprasad Rao answer to make the indicators work if they are outside the main carousel div. It works with every element that has the `data-target` property, not just `li`

```
$('.carousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var index = $(e.relatedTarget).index();

    $('[data-target="#' + $(this).prop('id') + '"]').each(function (i) {
        if (i === index) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code also for **bootstrap4**

```
$('#your-slide-div').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
            $holder = $( ".carousel-indicators li.active" );
            $holder.next( "li" ).addClass("active");
            if($holder.is(':last-child'))
            {
                $holder.removeClass("active");
                $(".carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
            }
            $holder.removeClass("active");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Guruprasads code does not activate the correct indicator when moving to the previous slide.
Here is my more generic solution.

Set the data-target attribute on your ol-element to the id of your carousel:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators" data-target="#myCarousel">
```

and include the following js code:

```
function initCarouselIndicators() {
    $(".carousel-indicators[data-target]").each(function (i, indicators) {
        var targetId = indicators.dataset.target;
        if (targetId != "") {
            var $carousel = $(targetId);
            $carousel.bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
                var $targetSlide = $(e.relatedTarget);
                var index = $targetSlide.index();
                $('.carousel-indicators[data-target="' + targetId + '"] li').removeClass('active')
                $('.carousel-indicators[data-target="' + targetId + '"] li:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('active');
            });
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    initCarouselIndicators();
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7q8so428/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using `slid.bs.carousel`

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  $('.carousel-indicators li').removeClass('active')
  var index = $(e.target).find('.active').index();
  $('.carousel-indicators li').eq(index).addClass('active');
})
```